# Error in javascript function

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the following code

```
function xhi(aax)
{
var aby=document.getElementById(aax);

aby.style.bottom=(parseInt(aby.style.bottom)+(screen.height-42)/10)+'px';

if(parseInt(aby.style.bottom)<(screen.height-42))setTimeout('xhi("'+aax+'")',25);
    }
```

When i run this code the function calls itself only two times . second time **aby.style.bottom** becomes Null.Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the bottom value. It might be crazy, but if the value is something like 008, 010, etc.
parseInt treats the number as **octal**. In order to avoid this, use :

```
   parseInt(aby.style.bottom,10)
```

Why are you using bottom? I believe the best approach is the top attribute.

If everything else fails, jQuery has some nice functions to animate and to grab those style attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try after removing from your code `+'px'` .